# Program appears to leak memory, but no memory leak detected

Tags: c++, memory

I'm working on a program currently which had a few memory leaks, and I managed to fix them by writing a class called `Memory`, incorporating it as a base class for all my other classes, and writing allocation and de-allocation functions into the `Memory` class. Each time memory is allocated or de-allocated, the details, including the class and function that made the call, would be recorded into a vector. This allowed me to write algorithms to analyse the results and point me in the direction of any memory leaks in my program.

I've finally reached the point where the analysis finds no leaks in the program (all recorded allocations had matching de-allocations). However, when I disable the `Memory` functionality with a pre-processor macro (to make sure that memory isn't being used up by the vectors), I can still find what appear to be memory leaks. I do this by running the test functions in a loop and watching the Task Manager as I do so: the memory usage steadily increases, despite the "Memory Management" vectors being out of action, and the tests returning no results when active.

I've made sure, through a solution wide search, that the keyword `new` is never used, except for in the memory management functions. All that those functions to, when debugging is deactivated, is allocate a new piece of memory and return the address, just as if I had used the `new` keyword directly.

I'm really just wondering if there is some kind of C++ anomaly that could be causing the program to consume memory, or if it's simply a problem in my debugging algorithms that is causing it to miss a leak. I can post code if necessary; it's a little long and tedious, but I can try and re-create the problem on a smaller scale - just let me know!

Thanks in advance for any suggestions, and I know there's not much to work from without the code - I'm just looking for any kind of quirk in the language that might be causing this, not so much for *where* the leak is in my code. Again, I'm happy to post code if necessary.

Comment: One word - `valgrind`. Long version: you do not need to reinvent the wheel, `valgrind` is being implemented for years, it's amazing tool, which gives you plenty of information, 99.99% of the time is right and detailed enough. Also, what makes you think, there's a leak? If the memory usage of the exe us growing - it's normal, most of the time, once some memory is dedicated to a process, it's not returned back to the OS (to be easier and faster to retrieve later, if needed).

Comment: I would have to agree with you, *but* I've spent about a week before attempting to get Valgrind working, to no avail. Do you know of a reliable Valgrind distribution for windows that you could point me towards?

Comment: Do your "memory management functions" interact properly with container allocators?

Comment: Steadily-increasing memory usage can just mean that your program is steadily using more memory without any leaks.

Comment: @BradSullivan - oh, Windows.. I see the problem. Can't help, there should be a way to run it in Windows, but I've never tried.

Comment: If it's on Windows, try e.g. Dr Memory.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I've implemented the "Test" function in a way that all of the memory should be de-allocated through class destructors each time the function returns, as they will go out of scope.

Comment: @KirilKirov From memory, I've seen some supposed "Valgrind for windows" distributions, but they're all sketchy and unreliable at best. I couldn't get them working.

Also, I wasn't aware that this is normal behaviour. Would the memory be returned to the OS if the program used up too much of it? I could run it for a longer period of time and see what happens?

Comment: @BradSullivan Right, but say each time you call the function, you use a bit more memory than the last time. Then you will see a steady increase.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz That's a good point.. The function doesn't rely on any external or `static` values, incremental or otherwise. I will step through my code though to make sure none of the nested calls do so. Thanks.

Comment: David means that the system-wide memory management may not release some of your previously allocated pages. There is two levels of memory management : one internal to your process (free/allocated chunks) and one external to it (allocated pages). So you may not have memory leak but increasing process space.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Okay, that's helpful.. So if, as I suggested before, I run it for a long enough time, it should de-allocate the build-up eventually? I'm trying to be very pedantic about finding and fixing memory management problems here, because I plan on reusing the code as a base for other projects later on.

Comment: On windows you could try VisualLeakDetector

Comment: Also, speaking of Windows, I remember having a problem with growing usage without a leak, that finally I resolved with a to call HeapSetInformation at the beginning of execution to enable LFH (the problem manifested itself on XP only, in an app with lots of small allocations).

Comment: Well, badly, most system do not release allocated pages. Try to allocate a gigabyte, release it, you will be able to observe that your process space is about 1 gigabyte long until its end. I don't know how Windows manage this, but on most *nix systems it works that way. This may not be a real problem as there is swapping mechanism and *virtual* allocations (means that if you allocate but don't use the memory the system don't really allocate pages). If you really need to control this, then you must write your own allocation system (see `brk` on *nix).

Comment: This seems like an odd thing for operating systems to do.. When I look at the task manager, other programs seem to remain stable in their memory usage. Is this just a case of the developers 'writing their own allocation systems', as you said, to handle the memory better?

Answer (score 4):

There are other ways of leaking memory, for example with GDI not calling DeleteObject on resources allocated yourself.

If you are using Visual Studio on windows, you could use the CRT's built-in memory leak detection functions:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x98tx3cf.aspx

Comment: I've used the cross referenced CRT tools. It's not pretty but definitely does the job. Using `_CrtSetBreakAlloc(...);` is a very effective way of landing you on the offending allocation in a leak.

Comment: I'm using CLion, but I've moved my code to Visual Studio before for better debugging capabilities. I'll try it - Thanks!

Comment: If you use CLion with the visual studio compiler you can stick to CLion, as this is a feature of the runtime, not of the IDE.